# (swift)initial view controller call tableview controller without hitting any button

Tags: ios, swift

i have tried to do this with following code. however, it doesn't work.

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

is there any ways to call other view controller without hitting button?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let controller  =  WKUserContentController()
    controller.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "JSListener")
    configuration.userContentController = controller

    let webview = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: configuration)
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index1", withExtension: "html")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    self.view = webview
    webview.loadRequest(request)

     let secondViewController:UIViewController = OurTableViewController()
    self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move

```
let secondViewController:UIViewController = OurTableViewController()
self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to viewDidAppear like that

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let secondViewController:UIViewController = OurTableViewController()
    self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: some error throw.      ableView Tutorial[12959:283655] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:6573
2016-05-24 11:14:53.402 TableView Tutorial[12959:283655] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier ourCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'